# Scala: Find all instances of matching regex and store in array

Tags: regex, scala

I have a string in Scala. I am trying to find all occurrences of a certain tag and find the text that is enclosed in the tag, storing the results in an array.

So for example, if my string is `val string = "<p> c </p> <p> a </p> <p> t </p>"`
The result I am looking for is:

```
val result = ["c","a","t"]
```

What is the best way to do this? Thanks!
Note: I am certain the tag type I am searching for will never appear nested inside another instance of itself, if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slight modification to Tony's suggestion.

```
val string = "<p> c </p> <p> a </p> <p> t </p>"
val re = "(?<=<p>)([^<]*)(?=</p>)".r
re.findAllMatchIn(string).map(_.toString.trim).toArray
// res0: Array[String] = Array(c, a, t)
```

The `.trim` part is optional.

Answer (score 0):

The following expression will match all letters between `<p>` and `</p>`.

```
(?<=<p>)[^<>]*(?=<\/p>)
```

Your list of matches should produce the result you are looking for.

Try the following to get a list of matches:

```
val reg = "(?<=<p>)[^<>]*(?=<\/p>)".r
val str = "<p> c </p> <p> a </p> <p> t </p>"
val matches = reg.findAllIn(str)

while (matches.hasNext) {

    val match = matches.next

}
```

Comment: How can I use this regex to actually create the array I want? Sorry, I am quite new to Scala.

Comment: @user308485 I added an example to my answer, however I also have no experience with scala and am unsure if it would work.

Comment: Just tested. It seems to compile, but doesn't seem to produce the expected result, just an empty iterator.

Comment: @user308485 Try the loop I added to the answer. Could you loop through the matches and add the data to an array?

Comment: I can try, but this would be considered poor practice in a functional language like Scala.

Comment: @user308485 Ya I agree, but unfortunately I don't know much about scala. Maybe this answer could be of help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066170/scala-regexps-how-to-return-matches-as-array-or-list